# Call CellFormatting when DataGridView is populated

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to trim the cells in the DataGridView when it's populated with data.

I can't figure out how to call the CellFormatting event from within the DataBindingComplete Event. Surely it's as simple as;

```
    private void iCBOMHDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        iCBOMHDataGridView_CellFormatting();
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to call the event handler method yourself. Just add the handler to the event and the handler will be called when the event raised.

Comment: I'm searching for a particular string in the datagrid. When it's populated each cell contains whitespace on the end. Thus it can't find the string even though I can see the value in the cells. Once it's searched the datagrid it then runs the trim but I need the trim to occur when the datagrid is populated

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar that might help. In my case, I am setting an inactive user's whole row to gray text, but it is still cell formatting:

```
        dgvUsers.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dgvUsers_CellFormatting);
        this.Controls.Add(dgvUsers);
```

The lines above happen before you dgvUsers.Enabled = true; The grid has been loaded, but not displayed. Then the handler that gets called is:

```
    private void dgvUsers_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        if (row != null && row.Row.ItemArray[7].Equals("N"))
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            dgvUsers.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

The main difference between the cell styling I do and yours is that I am not working with the actual values in the cells, just their styling.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can get the CellFormatting to work when a value is found in the DataGrid, but that requires me to edit the cell before the KeyPress event I have that looks for the value. The problem in having is the timing of my CellFormatting, it needs to happen when the datagridview is populated so that the values can be found